# Does Linux clear set-group-ID bit for a file is the group ID of the file doesn't match?

Tags: linux, chmod

I was going through the amazing book `The Linux Programming Interface`. In that chapter 15, section 15.4 page no 304, it is written that:

> For this reason, when an unprivileged process (one that doesn't have the **CAP_FSETID** capability) calls `chmod()` (or `fchmod()`) on a file whose group ID is not equal to the effective group ID or any of the supplementary group IDs of the process, the kernel always clears the set-group-ID permission bit. This is a security measure designed to prevent a user from creating a set-group-ID program for a group of which they are not a member.

I got a doubt that if this is the case, a unprivileged process can specify set-group-ID flag in `mode` argument in `open()` during file creation. The kernel doesn't clear the set-group-ID bit in that case. In my understanding the kernel should do this because of the reason mentioned. Why this behavior is only with `chmod()`?

Comment: Well, what happens when you try? Is the flag cleared or not?

Comment: @larsks, I asked the reason in the question, trying it out doesn't explain the reason. If you don't know the answer at-least don't down-vote it.

Comment: You said, " I really don't know if the kernel does the flag clear with the open() also or not." The way to answer that question is to try it. If you've already try it and have confirmed the behavior, then you should rewrite your question to ask something else.

Comment: @larsks, Now I have rewritten the question, after confirming the behavior.

Comment: In the usual case, when a process creates a file, the new file gets the group owner from the process, and following that rule, the same process could do the `chmod()` to add set-group-ID bit. Of course, as Stephen points out, a setgid directory is an exception.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel [clears the flag if it’s combined with group execution permissions](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3.1/source/fs/inode.c#L2483). You can test this with the following program:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    exit(1);
  }

  if (open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 02755) < 0) {
    perror("open");
  }
}
```

Create a directory, change it to a group of which you’re *not* a member, and make it setgid so that files created there are owned by the group. Then run the above program to create an executable file; you’ll see that the permissions end up being 755, not 2755.

If you change the permissions in the program to 02644, the resulting file will have permissions 2644; but that doesn’t confer anything on Linux.